# Save data and get it at another page - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am making switcher between themes. And i have problem. If i switched for example from dark mode to light mode at one page, other pages do not change theme. 
How can i change theme of all pages in my app?
Or i can just reload app? If yes, how i can do this?

For all saving I am using AsyncStorage

Help me please

```js
FirstPage.js

..///


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
    isEnabled: '',
    theme: '',
    loading: true
       }
       
  }

  async componentDidMount() {

   const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('theme')
   this.setState({
     theme: value,
     isEnabled: value == "black" ? true : false,
     loading: false
   })
   this.props.navigation.setParams({
    Theme: value == "black" ? "#171717" : "white"
  });
  }

  onSave = async (data) => {
    const { text } = this.state

        await AsyncStorage.setItem("theme", data);
        this.setState({
          theme: data
        })
        Expo.Updates.reload();
    
}

  toggleSwitch = () => {
    this.setState({ 
      isEnabled: this.state.isEnabled ? false : true,
    })
    if (this.state.isEnabled) {
      this.onSave("white")
    }
    else {
      this.onSave("black")
    }
  }

    render() {
      if (this.state.loading) {
        return (
          <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
            <ActivityIndicator />
          </View>
        );
      }
      const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
          

          <Text style={[styles.menuItem]}>Dark theme</Text>
  <Switch
        trackColor={{ false: "#767577", true: "#db0202" }}
        thumbColor={this.state.isEnabled ? "#f4f3f4" : "#f4f3f4"}
        onValueChange={this.toggleSwitch}
        value={this.state.isEnabled}
        style={{marginLeft: 10}}
      />


      <Text>{this.state.theme}</Text>
      <Text>{this.state.isEnabled ? "true" : "false"}</Text>


    

        )
    }
}

SecondPage.js

..//

class CoursesScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

        theme: '',
        fontLoaded: false,
        loading: true
    }
  }

  
    async componentDidMount() {

    

    componentWillMount() {
      this.onLoad();
  }

  onLoad = async () => {
    
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('theme')
     this.setState({
       theme: value,
       loading: false
     })
     this.props.navigation.setParams({
      Theme: value == "black" ? "#171717" : "white"
    });
}


    render() {
      if (this.state.loading) {
        return (
          <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
            <ActivityIndicator />
          </View>
        );
      }
 const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

            return (


                  ..//
            );
  }
}
```

Comment: You could save the mode in Redux (and also in Async Storage). Then connect all your screens to that property in redux so they know if the theme is dark or light. Also, save that in async so that when the user re-enters the app the selected theme is applied.

Answer (score 0):

you are asking for logical solution so i am not going to write code here instead i wanna share few tricks that might help you to get the job done..

1. if your application is not that much big and you don't wanna big changes in your project, here's what i did in my very first small project in react-native.
   just save your theme value into your AsyncStorage and also change your state for that screen for reflection of your theme, as you are doing, right.
   now here what you can do is when you closed the setting screen, before getting focus into any other screen you can fetch the data from your AsnycStorage and set data in your new screen state. you can use focus Event of ReactNevigation's as like this

   useEffect(() => {
   const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus",()=>{

   //fetchSettings()
   })

   return unsubscribe;

   },[navigation])

and at the in last if other screens are stacked inside of this screen you may not need to fetch data again and again you can just pass the settingsData from navigation.
i know this is not the best way to to this thing but having 4 or 5 screens it does the job well.

2. Now this is the best method to do the job,
   but you have to know about Context API.
   i was using react-native-paper and it has a theme provider. you just have to create different themes and wrap the react-native-theme provider inside your theme context.
   refer all of your app component's color to the theme.
   now all you have to do is when user switch the theme, set user's choice in storage for letter use and use your context api to change the theme variable.
   https://www.seishin.me/dynamic-switching-of-themes-in-react-native-app-the-funky-way-with-hooks/
   this is the better way of making this theme functionality done.
   also its not important to use react-native-paper, you can do this on your own way. or use other theme providers